# Browser fetch autorization 403

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get data from API, I get it with Node & Postman, but I can't make it work on the browser.
I get 403 Forbidden (anonymous).
Is it my problem or maybe something that's supposed to be enabled in the server?

```
var urlAPI = "http://example.com/api/v1/";
var uname = 'username';
var pass = 'password';

var headers = new Headers();
headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(uname + ':' + pass));

fetch(urlAPI, {
    mode: 'no-cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: headers
})
.then(function () {
        console.log("ok");
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("error: " + err);
    });
```

Comment: How do you send your credentials when using the browser?

Comment: Probably, it is a problem related to CORS. Browsers have security mechanisms to prevent unauthorized cross-origin access. Can you provide more information? I think you can use credentials: 'omit', since you already building into the header. Also check if the server allow CORS.